# How to print take something out of a list and store it elsewhere

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a music key theory test.

In order to achieve something else that I won't explain right now here (maybe I will later though if this doesn't work), I need to take the root chord out of the list, store it somewhere else, and call back upon it for the user input when they are asked what key the chords come from.

I don't know how to do this, but I am pretty sure it is possible. I would love it if someone could help me. After I have this problem sorted out I will be much further.

Before, I was trying to find someway to have the actual variable represent the variable, while representing what the variable contains. So then after printing the randomized chords from the variable, the user can input the key from which the chords come from, which I have as the variable. But I don't think that will work.

```
import random

print('Key Theory Werkout')

Dmajor = {'D','E-','F⌗-','G','A','B-','C⌗dim'}
Gmajor = {'G','A-','B-','C','D','E-','F⌗dim'}
Cmajor = {'C','D-','E-','F','G','A-','Bdim'}
Fmajor = {'F','G-','A-','Bb','C','D-','Edim'}
Bbmajor = {'Bb','C-','D-','Eb','F','G-','Adim'}
Ebmajor = {'Eb','F-','G-','Ab','Bb','C-','Ddim'}
Abmajor = {'Ab','Bb-','C-','Db','Eb','F-','Gdim'}
Dbmajor = {'Db','Eb-','F-','Gb','Ab','Bb-','Cdim'}
Cxmajor = {'C⌗','D⌗-','E⌗-','F⌗','G⌗','A⌗-','B⌗dim'}
Gbmajor = {'Gb','Ab-','Bb-','Cb','Db','Eb-','Fdim'}
Fxmajor = {'F⌗','G⌗-','A⌗-','B','C⌗','D⌗-','E⌗dim'}
Bmajor = {'B','C⌗-','D⌗','E','F⌗','G⌗','A⌗dim'}
Cbmajor = {'Cb','Db-','Eb-','Fb','Gb','Ab-','B-dim'}
Emajor = {'E','F⌗-','G⌗-','A','B','C⌗-','D⌗dim'}
Amajor = {'A','B-','C⌗-','D','E','F⌗-','G⌗dim'}

questions = [Dmajor, Gmajor, Cmajor, Fmajor, Bbmajor, Ebmajor, 
Abmajor, Dbmajor, Cxmajor, Gbmajor, Fxmajor, Bmajor, Cbmajor, 
Emajor, Amajor]

print('Difficulty:Easy, Hard')

begin = input("Choose Difficulty:")
if begin == 'easy':
    while begin == "easy":
        q = random.choice(questions)
        qq = random.sample(list(q), 7)
        print(qq)
        answer = input('Please Provide the key:')
        if answer == q
'''HERE IS THE PROBLEM. Lets say the code outputs F, A-, Bb, C, D- 
for Dmajor. How can I have the user type in Dmajor and have it 
print correct, or incorrect? I am thinking I will have to put . 
entire blocks for each question, and then have the easy choose 
random out of all of those questions and that will be how I have to     
do it. But maybe there is an easier way.
'''
            print("correct")
```

I would like it to tell the user if they are correct or wrong, while keeping the randomness of questions, and chords it spits out exactly the way it is. 
What do I need to do?

Comment: Use `if eval(answer) == q:` ... and of course, read about the dangers of using `eval`

Comment: It works! I'll read the dangers. The other guy Rostan's solution works too, so since there are dangers about eval I guess I will use his. Thanks so much though. I love this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try using a dictionary to represent your questions, like this:

```
questions = {
  'Dmajor': {'D','E-','F⌗-','G','A','B-','C⌗dim'},
  'Gmajor': {'G','A-','B-','C','D','E-','F⌗dim'},
  'Cmajor': {'C','D-','E-','F','G','A-','Bdim'},
  'Fmajor': {'F','G-','A-','Bb','C','D-','Edim'},
  'Bbmajor': {'Bb','C-','D-','Eb','F','G-','Adim'},
  'Ebmajor': {'Eb','F-','G-','Ab','Bb','C-','Ddim'},
  'Abmajor': {'Ab','Bb-','C-','Db','Eb','F-','Gdim'},
  'Dbmajor': {'Db','Eb-','F-','Gb','Ab','Bb-','Cdim'},
  'Cxmajor': {'C⌗','D⌗-','E⌗-','F⌗','G⌗','A⌗-','B⌗dim'},
  'Gbmajor': {'Gb','Ab-','Bb-','Cb','Db','Eb-','Fdim'},
  'Fxmajor': {'F⌗','G⌗-','A⌗-','B','C⌗','D⌗-','E⌗dim'},
  'Bmajor': {'B','C⌗-','D⌗','E','F⌗','G⌗','A⌗dim'},
  'Cbmajor': {'Cb','Db-','Eb-','Fb','Gb','Ab-','B-dim'},
  'Emajor': {'E','F⌗-','G⌗-','A','B','C⌗-','D⌗dim'},
  'Amajor': {'A','B-','C⌗-','D','E','F⌗-','G⌗dim'},
}
```

Then, you select a random question like this:

```
key = random.choice(list(questions))
set = questions[key]
sample = random.sample(set, 7)
```

Now, you only have to check if `answer` is equal to `key`.